# df shows negative values for used

Tags: filesystems

I am running Centos 7 and have an issue that the server ran out of space, was able to get in after a bad reboot and cleared temp files. Then cleared backups and server was back.

Since then I spotted that the disk size from the monitoring was actually going down, not what  I expected. Since then the negative size is increasing.

[image]

```
    Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     16G  164M   16G   2% /run
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root  498G  -41G  539G    - /
/dev/sda1                509M  312M  198M  62% /boot
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/997
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/10005
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
[root@srv ~]# Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                     16G  164M   16G   2% /run
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root  498G  -41G  539G    - /
/dev/sda1                509M  312M  198M  62% /boot
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/997
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/10005
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: Did you check the filesystem for errors?